# Laravel SSH on Windows Server

Tags: laravel, ssh, openssh

I have a Laravel 4.2 project hosted on one server (Server **A**), and I need to be able to upload files from this application and the files be transferred to a Windows server which is on the same local network (Server **B**).

I have installed OpenSSH on the Windows server and started the service. I can confirm that this is working because I can connect successfully in a terminal on Server **A**.

In the Laravel project I have created the connection in the app/config/remote.php file.

But when I try to run a command in the Laravel project on Server **A** by using the following code:

```
SSH::into('ServerB')->run(['IF EXIST folder (echo YES) ELSE (echo NO)'], function($line){
    echo $line.PHP_EOL;
});
```

I get the following error:

```
unpack(): Type N: not enough input, need 4, have 1
```

I'm receiving this error for every command I try to run on Server **B**. Strangely, if I try to use the same code but point it to a Linux server, the code works fine. This would lead me to believe that the SSH server is probably set up incorrectly on Server **B**, but the fact that I can connect via SSH to Server **B** from Server **A** in a terminal window confuses the whole matter!

Does anyone know the meaning of the error I'm receiving?

Comment: On which PHP version your Laravel 4.2 project is hosted?

Comment: I don't know Laravel very well, but I've found a similar problem report on phpeclib, that was fixed last year: https://github.com/terrafrost/phpseclib/commit/684d6eed0e2fc3045c9169685ce135a14474abef

Comment: post your log `echo $ssh->getLog();` also check your host and firewall

Comment: `unpack(): Type N: not enough input, need 4, have 1` The error is self explanatory that You are not providing enough input as the program is expecting 4 but you are giving one input

Comment: Sounds more like a server permission issue than a Laravel issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel 4.2's SSH is Facade that will resolve to `Illuminate\Remote\RemoteManager`. Its `into()` method will return `Illuminate\Remote\Connection` instance which then use `SecLibGateway` instance that encapsulate `phpseclib` library. `SecLibGateway` will return instance of phpseclib's `System_SSH_Agent` (see SSH_Agent.php in `vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib/System` directory in Laravel 4.2 installation). Inside System_SSH_Agent's constructor, at line 248:

```
$this->fsock = fsockopen('unix://' . $address, 0, $errno, $errstr);
```

It opens socket connection to unix://. OP said SSH works in Linux server but not in Windows server. I believe this may be the culprit. There are few calls to PHP's `unpack()` function such as at line 274:

```
$length = current(unpack('N', fread($this->fsock, 4)));
```

It calls unpack() with type N with 4 number required input. Somehow fsock is not valid and that cause error message to occured.

Answer (score 5):

This is likely to be an issue with `phpseclib`. Check if you have the latest version installed, update if possible.

Answer (score 1):

It seems this kind of errors appears when "the warning appears when the input data is not correct" [cfr this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29941911/php-warning-unpack-type-n-not-enough-input-log-entry)

This could be due to a setting in php.ini, ie "magic_quotes_runtime works by adding backslashes in content read from external sources, like textfiles, effectively destroying binary input like an .mo-file, and also destroying configuration-settings read from the database..." [cfr this post](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/php-warning-unpack-lta-hreffunctionunpackgtfunctionunpackltagt-type-v-n)